# JS регулярное выражение добавить пробел только 1 раз

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, input

При вводе данных **Имя Фамилия** разрешить использование только одного пробела и исключить ввод цифр или других символов кроме букв

```
name.replace(/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-яё\s]/gi, '');
```

Я только изучаю регулярные выражения. Мне нужно что бы пробел можно было использовать только 1 раз т.е \s

Comment: а как в целом звучит задача? У вас сейчас регулярка запрещает вводить вообще любые буквы и пробелы

Comment: Задача заключается в вводе Имя Фамилия и исключить ввод цифр или других символов кроме букв

Comment: А как именно вы видите решение задачи? Заменой любого кроме первого пробела на пустую строку или каким-то иным образом?

Comment: `[^]` - означает все кроме тех символов, что в скобках,т.е. вы наоборот разрешили ТОЛЬКО цифры и символы

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]*\s?[a-zA-Z]*$` тут только английские буквы, но не сложно добавить и русские ( пробел не обязателен, если он все таки обязателен, то вместо `?` используйте `{1}` )

Comment: @ThisMan, Тогда у вас и одно слово с начальным или конечным пробелом отработает.

Comment: @And ну да, звездочки на плюсики поменять)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю различия использования знака ^. Прочитав в интернете написано другое, вы говорите другое. Данный способ ^[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]+$ не дает мне вводить после 1 символа(он все стирает) [^a-zA-Z]+\s?[^a-zA-Z] а тут наоборот работает.

Comment: после того как выполнится функция replace я возвращаю из функций с помощью return тем самым в инпут символы пишутся нужным способом.

Comment: `^(?!.* .* )[A-Za-zА-Яа-я ]+$` Что нибудь такое, плюс данного способа, что совпадение начнется с первого символа ввода, и перестанет проходить валидацию после ввода цифры или второго пробела.

Comment: @PotroNik, Тогда у вас и одно слово с начальным или конечным пробелом отработает.

Comment: @And я так понимаю это на валидацию вводимых символов, т.е. исключить первый пробел можно, но вот с последним пробелом уже проблема, при вводе пробела между именем и фамилией все сломается. А что бы исключить пробел вначале сделать так `^(?!.* .* )[^ ][A-Za-zА-Яа-я ]+$
`

Comment: @PotroNik, да что за бред. Вам выше написали, тут поправить 2 секунды `^[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]+$` - - единственное добавить русские буквы. Я хотел сделать другим способом, но увидел, что в `js` все с этим плохо и не работает, по этому, кроме такого костыля, ничего не придумать больше. на счет `а-я` - этого мало, там нет в наборе `ё`.

Comment: @And добавил ответ, то о чем я говорил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю js, но вот что примерно получилось на онлайн валидацию вводимых данных. Думаю не совсем правильно, но как вариант.

В поле не будут печататься символы не подходящие под шаблон.

```js
var reg = new RegExp('^(?!.* .* )(?!^ )[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё ]*$', 'gm');
var oldres;
$('#choose').on('input', function(e) {
  const regres = $(e.target).val().match(reg);
  if (regres != null) {
    oldres = regres[0];
  } else {
    $(e.target).val(oldres);
  }
  //  console.log($(e.target).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="choose">Введите имя:</label>
    <input id="choose">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая вроде подходит под условия.

```js
let n1 = 'Imya Familia';
let n2 = 'Imya1 Familia';
let n3 = 'Imya  Familia';
let n4 = ' Imya Familia';
let n5 = 'Imya Familia ';

let reg = /^[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+\s[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+$/gi;

console.log(reg.test(n1));
console.log(reg.test(n2));
console.log(reg.test(n3));
console.log(reg.test(n4));
console.log(reg.test(n5));
```